# Which of these are propositions? Comment on their truth values if not, give a reason why it is not.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Which of these are propositions? Comment on their truth values if that's the case, if not, explain why it isn't a proposition

> 1. The stars in the sky look bright at night.
> 2. Travelling is tiring.
> 3. Tom loves Marie.

I have having trouble reasoning with these sentences.

1. Depending on where it is around the world , the stars can be looking brightly, or it can be a cloudy night
2. Depends on the person
3. Either True or false -> proposition right?

I don't get it for 1 and 2 and I want to know if 3 is correct

Comment: 1. As opposed to how they look during the day? If the stars look bright, it must be night...........is that true?

Comment: Does it not depend on the choices of the modeller of the particular domain? Little in life is truly boolean: "loves" can be expressed on a scale and with different characteristics (agápe, éros, philía, and storgē) . For an example in real-life, a transistor in a computer circuit will have a voltage within a range of say 0-6v, but we can say it is on (True) if voltage > 3.3, else off (False). When the modeller defines the terms, they must also define the thresholds for True and False.

Answer (score 0):

A proposition, according to AoPS, is this: "  a statement ( or proposition) is an assertion that is either true or false ( but never both)." None of these questions have much value in mathematics or logic IMO.

1. Not a proposition ( it is really an opinion on whether something is bright or not), unless you give a definition of the brightness of something, like the luminosity or magnitude of a star
2. Again, it is really an opinion, so no absolute true or false
3. This question is a propsition I think. Its either true or false.

Comment: I think the only real reason to consider the third one a "proposition" if the two first aren't, is that "loves" is somehow a common example of something that beginning logic textbooks claims is a predicate that gives definite truth values. Really, though, whether whatever Tom feels about Marie should be count as "love" is as fuzzy and subjective as whether the stars are bright. Tom himself might not be able to give a definite answer if Marie asks him point blank ...

Comment: You are right... but these questions feel irrelevant to any field of math or logic anyway.